# How to import data in relational database to RDF?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, relational-database

How can I get data from a relational database into RDF?

Answer (score 5):

I suggest [D2RQ](http://www4.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/bizer/d2rq/) which can convert SPARQL (RDF query) into a relational SQL query.  You don't need to convert/export.

Answer (score 5):

The following document by the [ESW](http://esw.w3.org/topic/FrontPage) group, entitled [A Survey of Current Approaches for Mapping of Relational Databases to RDF](http://esw.w3.org/topic/Rdb2RdfXG/StateOfTheArt) , as the title suggests, lists the current protocols and available software for converting relational data to [RDF](http://www.w3.org/RDF/).